# You have earned the "xxx" badge back button bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, notifications

**Browser:** Chrome

When the bar at the top of the page appears when you earn a badge, and you then navigate to another page (I clicked on the recent icon), then go back, the bar reappears each time.

Comment: It's not browser specific - I've seen it in Firefox. A refresh of the page after dismissing the notification "fixes" the problem.

Comment: Are `XXX` questions allowed in Stack Overflow???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt that this is browser-specific. I *suspect* that the source initially delivered to the browser already contains the badge information, so when the source is reloaded from the cache it will show it again.

An AJAX call to get badge information would solve this but I suspect it would be a significant traffic hit (in terms of number of requests, not actual bandwidth).

Comment: Can Jon just go ahead and be awarded ∞ now?  :)  It'll save some wear on the system.

Comment: Can we experiment and not guess?

Answer (score 0):

That notice bar often sticks in the top of the browser until you click it away by the X or hit the link it shows up with.

If you navigate to another page, but don't click it away, it will keep on with the gentle reminder.

It's like when you check out the site for the first time, you'll see the bar. Click it away with the X and it won't show again unless you clear your cookies.